# Custom error page is not being displayed in chrome

Tags: java, jsp, google-chrome, exception

Below is my code for JdbsJsp.java

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" errorPage="/ErrorPage.jsp"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/saumil","root","root");
                Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2));
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }

        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my error page is as follows,

```
<%@page isErrorPage="true"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>An Exception has occured(probably SQLException)</h1>
        <%=exception.getMessage()%>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have purposely set the table name as 'emp'(there is no such table in the database) to display the error page. But instead of displaying an error page, I'am getting a completely blank screen. The message that of "An Exception has occured(probably SQLException)" is not getting displayed.
Hope anyone can guide me through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your JdbcJsp.jsp page instead of writing,

```
catch(Exception e)
{

}
```

write,

```
finally
{

}
```

from what I believe, the 'catch' is probably preventing your custom exception page from getting displayed.